# Python, Django Celery job interface upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 celery jobs not running

Tags: python, django, celery

Very New to Celery/Django
Over the weekend, we upgraded the ubuntu server to 20.04, and while the web interface is up and running and I can see the defined jobs when I attempt to run any job the job does not run.

I am not seeing any errors in the logs (assuming I am looking at the correct apache logs).

Everything is down and I am not sure where to debug celery. If I could find out where the jobs are located then I would try to run using the celery CLI.

Updated from ubuntu 16.04.
It is using mod_wsgi not using a virtual env that I can tell. I believe it is using the system python version 2.7.

I've tried restarting.

Any help/pointers are much appreciated.
[image: Jobs not starting]

The 2.7 python did stick around, probably as you suggested due to the upgrade.
It looks to be the default in the path:

```
/home/barrow/bin:/home/barrow/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
barrow@server:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
barrow@server:~$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

There are, of course, other versions of python sitting around.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5490352 Jun  2 04:49 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Jun  2 04:49 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3674216 Mar  8 06:02 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar  8 06:02 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Feb 20 16:02 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Feb 20 16:02 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4723808 Feb 20 16:02 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4723808 Feb 20 16:02 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
```

I am able to run the celery command in the CLI, so I removed that post here. I am "searching" for where the job might be. I can't wait until I understand this.

My thoughts are that I might be able to run the job using celery on the command line. Or worst case that would help with the debugging and eliminate is as a culprit.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu were you using before? There's probably a lot of details needed to be able to help you, including how your webapp is configured. You mentioned apache, are you using mod_wsgi, reverse proxy, or ? -- is your Python interpreter for mod_wsgi setup with a virtualenv? Are you using the system python or a separately installed one? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: When you ask "how the webapp is configured" what did you mean?



I've updated the original post with the information you mentioned.
I'm concerned with making changes I am not sure of since I don't want to make it worse. But I know that might be inevitable.
New to this company and the previous person left recovery instructions which talk about docker BUT I do not see that this instance is running in docker.

Comment: Between Ubuntu 16 and 18 (not to mention 20), I believe the default `python` binary went away. So any references to the system `python` on PATH will likely no longer work. That's probably an immediate concern. Python 2 went End-Of-Life before Ubuntu 20 was released, too. I'm surprised if you're using the system python the web app is up. I suppose the old version of Python may stick around if you upgraded, though.

Comment: I've added more info in the original post.